# Animate px.line line with plotly express

Tags: python, pandas, animation, plotly, wide-format-data

Learning plotly line animation and come across this question

My df:

|  | Date | 1Mo | 2Mo | 3Mo | 6Mo | 1Yr | 2Yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-02-12 | 4.66 | 4.77 | 4.79 | 4.89 | 4.50 | 4.19 |
| 1 | 2023-02-11 | 4.66 | 4.77 | 4.77 | 4.90 | 4.88 | 4.49 |
| 2 | 2023-02-10 | 4.64 | 4.69 | 4.72 | 4.88 | 4.88 | 4.79 |
| 3 | 2023-02-09 | 4.62 | 4.68 | 4.71 | 4.82 | 4.88 | 4.89 |
| 4 | 2023-02-08 | 4.60 | 4.61 | 4.72 | 4.83 | 4.89 | 4.89 |

How do I animate this dataframe so the frame has
`x = [1Mo, 2Mo, 3Mo, 6Mo, 1Yr, 2Yr]`, and 
y = the actual value on a date, eg `y=df[df['Date']=="2023-02-08"], animation_frame = df['Date']`?

I tried

```
plot = px.line(df, x=df.columns[1:], y=df['Date'], title="Treasury Yields", animation_frame=df_treasuries_yield['Date'])
```

No joy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you cannot pass multiple columns to the `animation_frame` parameter. But we can get around this by converting your `df` from wide to long format using `pd.melt` – for your data, we will want to take all of the values from `[1Mo, 2Mo, 3Mo, 6Mo, 1Yr, 2Yr]` and put them a new column called `"value"` and we will have a variable column called `"variable"` to tell us which column the value came from.

```
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['1Mo', '2Mo', '3Mo', '6Mo', '1Yr', '2Yr'])
```

This will look like the following:

```
          Date variable  value
0   2023-02-12      1Mo   4.66
1   2023-02-11      1Mo   4.66
2   2023-02-10      1Mo   4.64
3   2023-02-09      1Mo   4.62
4   2023-02-08      1Mo   4.60
...
28  2023-02-09      2Yr   4.89
29  2023-02-08      2Yr   4.89
```

Now can pass the argument `animation_frame='Date'` to `px.line`:

```
fig = px.line(df_long, x="variable", y="value", animation_frame="Date", title="Yields")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Derek for the answer, I actually need animation over time, therefore animation_frame="Date", the actual line should be 
```plot = px.line(df_long, x="variable", y="value", animation_frame="Date", title="Yields")```

Comment: @KaiZhang oh i see – i misunderstood, but will update the answer accordingly. thanks for accepting!